# Underground bundle of wires has a/c interference, slight noises on pairs of wires

Tags: power

Is there a way to mask a/c interference on a pair of underground wires. They are 14 guage wires. I have slight power from a 110 circuit that is bleeding over to several other wires in this bundle. This is causing the circuit low voltage or noise which is effecting the operation of a remote circuit pack. I need to isolate the influence with a device, but I don't know what to use.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use twisted wires - this cancels out most of the low-frequency noise
2. Use shields on wires you want to protect from interference
3. If your signals have useful frequencies above 60Hz, use a high-pass filter to suppress 60 Hz

Comment: Twisted pair wires are useful only if the receiving end accepts differential inputs, only then all common mode noise can be nulled.